# Install mbstring/libmbfl on PHP 5.3.14 (Apache2.2 version) on Windows server

Tags: php, apache2.2, mbstring

I want to use `simpleHTMLDom` in my development environment, a Windows server running `Apache 2.2` and `PHP 5.3.14` (downloaded from Apache). I want to enable `mbstring (extension=php_mbstring.dll)`, but I see the following error in the PHP logs when I restart Apache:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_mbstring.dll' in Unknown on line 0

The DLL file is there. I found on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) that mbstring needs libmbfl to work. I can not find how to get libmbfl to work though.

I can't find a DLL of any sort that loads libmbfl. How can I get simpleHTMLDom to work under my development environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this will help to install libmbfl then you can do this

https://github.com/moriyoshi/libmbfl